# 5 new entries for every existing row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
date,               product,   new_col,
2013/05/16,            A,
2013/05/18,            A,
2013/06/15,            A,
2013/05/16,            B,
2013/06/13,            B,
2013/06/20,            B
```

I am using SQL Server 2008.

For every existing entry, in `new_col` I need to store into `new_col` 5 previous calendar dates up to and including the date in the `date` column. E.g. for the 1st row in the above table, I need `5/16,5/15,5/14,5/13,5/12` in the `new_col`.

I have a lot of products in the table and a lot of dates for every product.

I have tried to partition the table based on these two columns but can't figure out a way to enter 5 days in the `new_col`.

Please help with any suggestions to do this.

Comment: Does this have to be done in SQL?  It may be much easier in an application or reporting layer.

Comment: Having a column with multiple values separated by comma is not a good idea at all.

Comment: What SQL server software are you using?

Comment: @MostyMostacho For _storage_ I agree, but I see this all the time in reporting.

Comment: i hv a db in sql and this is one of the existing table and am running a query on it.
so it needs to be in sql

Comment: Microsft SQL?  Oracle?  MySQL?

Comment: microsoft sql server 2008

Comment: My point is - how are you _displaying_ the results?  A report?  An Application?  Web Page?

Comment: you can calculate days by date operators given here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_dates.asp then concatenate the resultant string as here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177561.aspx

Comment: @DStanley - From OP's post: *I am using sql server 2008*.  I added the tag.

Comment: i need to then match these 3 col to another table and then sum the existing values in the other table. and the sum needed is only for the  past 5 days.

Comment: Please provide the **desired output** based on your sample data. If you have more requirements than you have listed in your post please add them there.

Comment: the results would also go in a table in the same db.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH cal AS (
    SELECT CAST('20130101' AS DATE) as cal_date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, cal_date)
    FROm cal 
    WHERE cal_date < CAST('20131231' AS DATE )
)
SELECT 
  [date],[product],
   new_col = STUFF((SELECT ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),cal.cal_date,111) 
              FROM cal 
              WHERE cal.cal_date BETWEEN DATEADD(day, -4, tbl.[date]) AND tbl.[date]
              ORDER BY cal.cal_date DESC      
              FOR XML PATH('')    
              ),1,1,'')
FROM tbl
OPTION (maxrecursion 0)
```

***<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d0de4/7)</kbd>***

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best solution but it's the first that popped into my head.  Also as people have been mentioning, you do not need to store this... you can call this function directly from whatever reporting solution you've deployed.  Was lazy about removing the last comma but that's pretty simple. Also feel free to adjust the datetime formatting as you see fit.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Sam ([Date] DATE, Product VARCHAR(10), NewCol VARCHAR(1000))
INSERT INTO dbo.Sam
SELECT '2013/05/16','A',NULL
UNION ALL SELECT '2013/05/18','A',NULL
UNION ALL SELECT '2013/06/15','A',NULL
UNION ALL SELECT '2013/05/16','B',NULL
UNION ALL SELECT '2013/06/13','B',NULL
UNION ALL SELECT '2013/06/20','B',NULL

GO


CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnGet4PreviousDates(@Date DATE, @Product VARCHAR(10))
    RETURNS VARCHAR(1000)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Out VARCHAR(1000) = ''


    SELECT @Out = @Out + CONVERT(VARCHAR,[Date],112) + ','
    FROM (
        SELECT TOP 5 [Date]
        FROM dbo.Sam
        WHERE Product = @Product
        AND [Date] < @Date
        ORDER BY [Date] DESC
    ) t

    RETURN @Out

END
GO

UPDATE dbo.Sam
SET NewCol = dbo.fnGet4PreviousDates([Date],Product)

SELECT * FROM dbo.Sam
```